# using a getter to bind a function that returns a promise object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript getters is a cool way to bind function calls to object definitions.  I've used it a number of times before, but in a recent problem I wanted to use it to bind a function that returns a jQuery promise object that gets used in a $.when...$.then chain.

It seems as though using a getter doesn't work the way I was expecting it to; specifically, $.then() doesn't wait for the bound function's promise object to be resolved when it uses the function definition that the getter returns.  However, if no getter is used and I just call the function directly, things work as expected.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Example:

```
var myObj = {
  asynch1: {
    a: 200,
    b: 300,
    get runAsynch3() {return function() {
      myCustomAsynchCode3(this.a, this.b);
      }
    },
  },
};

function myCustomAsynchCode1() {
  var df = $.Deferred();
  // do stuff that, when done, calls
  //  df.resolve();
  return df.promise();
}
function myCustomAsynchCode2() {
  var df = $.Deferred();
  // do stuff that, when done, calls
  //  df.resolve();
  return df.promise();
}
function myCustomAsynchCode3(val1, val2) {
  var df = $.Deferred();
  // do stuff that, when done, calls
  //  df.resolve();
  return df.promise();
}
```

If I make a call such as

```
var that = this;
$.when(myCustomAsynchCode1()).
  then(function() {
    return that.myCustomAsynchCode2();
  ).
  then(function() {
    return that.myObj.runAsynch3();
  });
```

runAsynch3() executes before myCustomAsynchCode2() resolves its promise object.

But, if I make a call like this

```
var that = this;
$.when(myCustomAsynchCode1()).
  then(function() {
    return that.myCustomAsynchCode2();
  ).
  then(function() {
    return myCustomAsynchCode3(that.myObj.a, that.myObj.b);
  });
```

everything works as expected - the promise objects are resolved without stepping on each other.

Comment: In some promise libraries (eq. `q`), there is a function `.all(arrayOfPromises)` for chaining promises. I haven't used promises with jQuery, but you could check `deferred.pipe()` whether it does the job you want?

Comment: I think pipe() has been deprecated as of jquery 1.8.  The suggested usage is then().  There is a way to provide an array of promises for execution by using apply(), but when I tested it it seemed as though the order of the array objects does not necessarily guarantee that they will be executed in that order.    I haven't looked at other libraries; just interested in jQuery's handling of the promise object.

Comment: What are you expecting `$.when(myCustomAsynchCode1)` to do?  `$.when` expects promises/deferreds as arguments.  But you are passing a function.

Comment: Also, post your test code that shows it is not working as expected.  Without knowing how/when you are resolving those promises it is hard to divine where the problem is.  It could just be a bug in your test code.

Comment: Made typo fix to myCustomAsynchCode1 such that it actually gets called; upon getting called, .when() gets its promise object as you mention.  The code that resolves each deferred works since I can call it using the same .when...then structure with success if I don't use the getter.  It's the use of the getter in the call that is causing issues, i.e. the way the code is being called.